# SHAP values and feature-target correlations contradict each other - why?

Tags: correlation, shapley-value

I am using SHAP values in a model explainability analysis and I am seeing a pattern of results where the SHAP values are clearly pointing in a positive or negative direction for most features, i.e. feature values are highly correlated with SHAP values. I interpret this as evidence of directional relationships between features and predictions.

Now the interesting part: I also calculated correlations between feature variables and the target variable, and in some cases the sign of the correlation flips - indicating the opposite relationship.

In short: the correlation between feature values and SHAP values and the correlation between feature values and target values are in disagreement.

E.g.:
r(feature, SHAP) = 0.71
r(feature, target) = -0.22

I have trouble interpreting this pattern. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

What you described seems like a manifestation of [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox). ML models usually have multiple interactions between their features so these "sign-reversal" phenomena might be associated with [confounding variables biasing the effect measurement](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-simpson/#ConfPearAnalPara). If you have a reproducible example it would be easier to comment further. I would also suggest looking at PDPs (partial dependency plots) both the ["standard" version](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/pdp.html#pdp) we get through marginalisation of feature  `x` as well as the ones we get via [SHAP](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/shap.html#shap-dependence-plot) (in later case go forward and colour-code individual point by the outcome so any underlying pattern is more obvious). They might include relevant information. Finally, maybe it is worth trying a ["glass-box" model](https://github.com/interpretml/interpret) (e.g. GAMs, [EBMs](https://interpret.ml/docs/ebm.html), etc.) such that the influence of feature `x` to the outcome is immediately quantifiable.

Comment: What is the difference between the partial R^2 and the SHAP Value for a linear regression model? (interpretation)

Comment: That is a great question as they have some obvious qualitative similarities. It is a rather involved one for the comment section though, so feel free to create a stand-alone question! :)

Comment: I have just created the question in the datascience section. I don't know if it's better to use the crossvalidation or stats section. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/116160/what-is-the-difference-interpretation-between-the-partial-r2-and-the-shap-val
Feel free to reply or to improve the question itself (English is not my language).